# Problem with the definition of Intersection Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm confused because of the definition of the intersection graph, i can draw the graph for the following sets and call it as `Intersection Graph`

$A1$ = {$0,2,4,6,8$}

$A2$ = {$0,1,2,3,4$}

$A3$ = {$1,3,5,7,9$}

$A4$ = {$5,6,7,8,9$}

$A5$ = {$0,1,8,9$}

each of the sets are vertices, and we have an edge between two sets if there exist at least an element common between them

but i need more **General** Definition, what is the Definition of `Intersection Graph` in a graph $G=(V,E)$

Comment: An [intersection graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph) is a graph formed from a collection of sets. Can you clarify what you mean by you want a definition of intersection graph in a graph $G=(V,E)$?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that an **intersection graph** is always based upon a family (collection) of sets. Assuming you have understood this, we have,

> A graph $G=(V,E)$ is called an intersection graph for a finite family $F$ of a non-empty set if there is a one-to-one correspondence between $F$ and $V$ such that two sets in $F$ have non-empty intersection if and only if their corresponding edges in $V$ are adjacent.

Taken from [Intersection Graphs: An Introduction, Madhumangal Pal, Annals of Pure and Applied Mathematics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.5468.pdf).